# Using facebook data for college research

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So, I have small project for college and I need to collect particular data from students. I was thinking about creating facebook app for short survey and collect users data like facebook likes, posts and education.

1. Can I use facebook data and api's for research? (read_stream permission seems like a problem)
2. Can I restrict apps usage on users education?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of rate limit restriction with Facebook apps. [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting)

You may need to have a counter to watch on this rate limit in your Facebook status fetching thread.

Comment: I'm not so experienced but I think I will not have problems with that because my estimations are that this app would have no more than 500 users (I would be happy with at least 200 because that's my minimum for research). And, as I understood, you are refering to sentence in brackets. Potential problem with read_stream is limited use and need for review if I use it. Would my app pass this review? That's my main concern.

Comment: @WizKid, could You suggest any other option for collecting previously described data? Or it's really not possible?

Comment: For likes you need user_likes

Comment: Ok, could you tell me just few more thing (You can post it as an answer so I can mark it as "accepted"). Is it ok, by facebook policy, to create and use apps for research? Is it ok to restrict app access on education (particular college)? And back to the read_stream, is there any legal way to get that permission for my research survey/application (it doesn't have to be in form of facebook app)?